# Conditional String Formatting Given Word Pattern Match R

Tags: r, replace, gsub, stringr

I'm trying to identify patterns in an R character vector and then replacement them with the same words but with a selective space added:

For example:  "52WkAvg Premium/Discount 52WkHigh"

I'd like to replace with "52WkAvg Premium/Discount [:whitespace:] 52WkHigh"

I've experimented with gsub and str_replace but am not sure how to would string together the replacement text match with the space.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you want, but is `gsub("(52WkAvg Premium/Discount)\\s+(52WkHigh)", "\\1  \\2", x)` the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear since I think you have the idea of what I'm after.  Is there a way to insert an NA between the "Premium/Discount" and "52WkHigh" provided that entire string matches?  Apologies but I'm new to string manipulation and it's been tricky for me.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just add the text `NA` between `\\1` and `\\2` above I reckon - give it a try.

Comment: Wow, that worked!  For future reference what does the \\1 and \\2 signify?  The position where the replacement is inserted?  In the prior example you had an actual whitespace between them, do you not need to use \\s?

Comment: The `\\n` represent 'capture groups' - each time you specify a pattern inside parentheses `"(one) (two)"` they correspond to `\\1` and `\\2` etc in the requested replacement. You don't use `\\s` in the replacement, just use a normal space as `\\s` can represent several types of space characters.

Comment: Thank you.  It's definitely complex.  Appreciate your help!